# Java Mail Authentication

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Trying to connect mail using java

Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No POP server defined. Use real server address instead of 127.0.0.1 in your account.
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at POP3Clint.main(POP3Clint.java:28)
Java Result: 1

---

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class POP3Clint {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


String host = "192.168.10.205";
  String user = "test";
  String password = "test";
  // Get system properties
  Properties properties = System.getProperties();

  // Get the default Session object.
  Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  // Get a Store object that implements the specified protocol.
  Store store = session.getStore("pop3");

  //Connect to the current host using the specified username and password.
  store.connect(host, user, password);

  //Create a Folder object corresponding to the given name.
  Folder folder = store.getFolder("inbox");

  // Open the Folder.
  folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

  // Get the messages from the server
  Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();

  // Display message.
  for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("------------ Message " + (i + 1) + " ------------");
  // Here's the big change...
  String from = InternetAddress.toString(messages[i].getFrom());
  if (from != null) {
  System.out.println("From: " + from);
  }
  String replyTo = InternetAddress.toString(
  messages[i].getReplyTo());
  if (replyTo != null) {
  System.out.println("Reply-to: " + replyTo);
  }
  String to = InternetAddress.toString(
  messages[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
  if (to != null) {
  System.out.println("To: " + to);
  }
  String cc = InternetAddress.toString(
  messages[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC));
  if (cc != null) {
  System.out.println("Cc: " + cc);
  }
  String bcc = InternetAddress.toString(
  messages[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.BCC));
  if (bcc != null) {
  System.out.println("Bcc: " + to);
  }
  String subject = messages[i].getSubject();
  if (subject != null) {
  System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
  }
  Date sent = messages[i].getSentDate();
  if (sent != null) {
  System.out.println("Sent: " + sent);
  }
  Date received = messages[i].getReceivedDate();
  if (received != null) {
  System.out.println("Received: " + received);
  }
  System.out.println();
  }

  folder.close(true);
  store.close();
  }
}
```

---EDITTED__

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
    at POP3Clint.main(POP3Clint.java:35)
Java Result: 1
```

this exception comes if we disable anitivirus

Comment: try with `smtp.gmail.com` as host , your username and password same as your gmail id and let us know.

Comment: @Skyscraper, Looks like your antivirus is proxying your mail request to localhost. Disable antivirus if you have any. Disable any web-shield running. Disable whatever is proxying your mail request.

Comment: Sorry, can you try with `pop.gmail.com`

Comment: @RaviTrivedi Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket
 at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:208)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
 at POP3Clint.main(POP3Clint.java:34)
Java Result: 1

Comment: after disabling antivrus

Comment: @Skyscraper, looks like protocol problem. Use pop3s and test ! Because gmail uses pop3s !

Comment: @RaviTrivedi i have debbgged my problem
the problem is responce from server
S: EOF

Comment: @Skyscraper, what do you mean ?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi see this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16336886/java-mail-authentication-and-connection..